# How fast do paw paw trees sucker up?

Tags: fruit-trees

A [pawpaw tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba) sounds amazing, so I'm considering growing some.

Is that a bad idea for a small yard? How fast do paw paw trees sucker up?

Comment: I think this question needs clarification, or it may be put on hold. Small yard can mean anything, so we need to know your measurements, and how much room you have for the tree. If you're only asking about size, as your title says, that's fine. If you care about whether it's suitable for your climate, you should add that part, including the average temperature range in your yard, not just the zone. More information about the tree would help too. Please edit these things in, because comments are harder to read and don't last forever. Thanks!

Comment: Could you specify what do you mean with "paw paw tree"?  Wikipedia knows *Asimina* (all genus), *Carica papaya* and *Vasconcellea pubescens* as paw paw trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My neighbor planted four pawpaws maybe ten years ago.
They haven't put out suckers, but the seeds have a high germination rate.
I pull or clip the ones on my side of the line at least a couple times a year.
Tasty fruit. [Need to find a few mammoths](https://www.americanforests.org/magazine/article/trees-that-miss-the-mammoths/) to eat the excess, so I don't spend so much time getting rid of saplings.

Comment: Why not have chickens instead of mammoths take care of the saplings?

Comment: Mammoths are traditional. Seeds may be a bit big for chickens. Perhaps goats?

Comment: I mean chickens eating the seeds, not spreading them.

Answer (score 0):

In another answer you said you were in USDA zone 4a.  The paw paw tree or [asimina triloba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba) is listed [here](http://www.pawpaw.kysu.edu/pawpaw/ppg.htm) as good to USDA zone 5 or temperatures no lower than  -15 def F/-26 deg C.  This doesn't mean you can't try from plants grown locally that might be more cold resistant.  It does mean you are taking a chance that any time there's a really cold winter the trees will be killed back to the ground. This puts your next harvest another five years away.

I notice they also require slightly acid (pH 5.5-7), deep, fertile, and well-drained soil.  You have to know your soil types to have success. For best fruit production they should be sited in full sun with protection from wind.  Perhaps a site with a shelter belt of evergreens would work well.

They also do not self pollinate and normal pollinators are [described](https://www.hort.purdue.edu/ext/HO-220.pdf) as "neither efficient or dependable".  The article recommends hand pollination for best fruit production.

After harvest ripe plants will only last two days at room temperature or a week at temperatures of 40 - 45 deg F (or approximately fridge temperature).

This tree is not ready for commercial fruit production due to the issues with specific habitat, pollination and storage but can be an interesting challenge for the home gardener.

Comment: http://www.manchestergardenclub.com/rick/Tropicals/Tropicals.htm paw paw is good to zone 4

Comment: That reference is from a gardener in USDA zone 5, says this right at the top of the page.  He doesn't give a reference to support hardiness in zone 4. This doesn't mean the paw paw is not hardy sometimes in zone 4.  It is at the limit of it's range.

Comment: Then why does the USDA say it grows in Canada, and Wisconsin: http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=ASTR

Comment: The USDA information is based on one reference from the vascular plants of canada here http://data.canadensys.net/explorer/en/search?view=map&1_f=16&1_o=EQ&1_v_1=Asimina+triloba which shows one occurrence of the plant in the warmest part of Ontario. Likely what was formerly Carolinian forest.  My copy of trees in Canada by Farrar shows a similar range map in the Canadian zone 6 or USDA 5 range.  Hardiness is tricky and variable from plant to plant.

Comment: Zone map was redone in 2012, with most areas getting half a zone warmer. If your info is older than that, you have to adjust: http://www.ars.usda.gov/is/pr/2012/120125.htm

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Good point. It would help if the OP told us what are the usual winter temperatures and the extraordinary lows are where they live.  I find every six or seven years you still get really cold temperatures for long enough to kill plants on the edge of hardiness